# Detecting available keys in a custom model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

Currently working with ASP.NET Core 2.2.0

I have a controller action (POST) that needs to support client requests with multiple arbitrarily named input parameters (I don't know in advance how many keys or their names).  My thought is that those parameters should be bound to a collection argument such as a `Dictionary<string,object>` in the controller action, but I'm flexible on that if there is another way.

I'm attempting a custom model binding to do this.  The available public interface to the value providers in the binding context appears to require that I know the key names in order to get values e.g.

```
valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("keyName");
```

Of course this won't help meet the stated requirement.

While debugging I found that the keys are there, hidden in a **private** part of the value provider, though I have not found a quality way to leverage that.

```
bindingContext.ValueProvider[1]._values.Keys
//_values is private
```

1. Is there some existing binder that I have missed that just does this?
2. Is there some public way to access the keys?
3. Is there some reason that the keys are fully hidden by design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did reach an adequate solution for this.  For others interested in discovering input parameter names, the key for me was to notice (while debugging) that while `bindingContext.ValueProvider` is declared as `IValueProvider`, its implemented type at run time (at least in my example) is `CompositeValueProvider`, which does add a useful method.  (MS documentation in this area is relatively unhelpful and my searches did not turn up an enlightening example)

For some supporting background, `CompositeValueProvider` supports the concept of an input parameter with a prefix in the name, though you don't need to use a prefix to accomplish my stated goal.  Two versions of syntax are supported, `prefix.name` and `prefix[name]`.

So I did something like the following:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// in my custom binder class derived from IModelBinder
public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
  var compositeValueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider as CompositeValueProvider;

  // For unprefixed names:
  // This also returns prefixes of prefixed names so you can recursively find the names
  var callerProvidedKeys = compositeValueProvider.GetKeysFromPrefix(""); 

  // or for a known prefix name
  //var callerProvidedKeys = compositeValueProvider.GetKeysFromPrefix(somePrefix);

  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in callerProvidedKeys) {
    // You can but don't have to access values through `CompositeValueProvider`
    var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(kvp.Value);
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

`GetKeysFromPrefix` returns `IDictionary<string,string>` where keys are the name portion only, and the value being the full parameter name including prefix.  The full name can then be used to extract the parameter value.